# Ansible - list tasks in role

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Is it possible to list the tasks in an Ansible role?

i.e. other than just grepping for `- name`, is there an out-of-the-box way of doing this?

Answer (score 10):

Create a simple playbook specifying the role and execute `ansible-playbook` with `--list-tasks` option.

But this will not list the tasks in dynamically included files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the play to display. ex:

```
ansible-playbook --list-tasks my-play.yml
```

And tasks in roles imported with include_role will not be displayed.
As @techraf said, this is dynamically loaded.